# Static Website on AWS s3 - Ajax Post to Formspree.io

Tags: jquery, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently trying to host a simple static website on AWS S3. I have just made a simple form which emails the form information to the client using http://formspree.io. The form is functional locally but from what I can find AWS only can handle GET and HEAD requests so I keep receiving a '405 Method Not Allowed' error with my ajax post.

Is there a way I can still use form spree even though I'm hosting on AWS S3? If not what is the best method of having a functional form on a website hosted on AWS S3?

Form code atm:

```
     <form id="contactform" role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="Website contact - PT Enquiry" />
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input id="email" type="email" name="_replyto" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                            <label>Phone Number</label>
                            <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" rows="6"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <button id="submitForm" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </form>
```

Ajax Script:

```
     $("#submitForm").on("click", function() {
        if ($.trim($("#email").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#name").val()) === "" || $.trim($("#message").val()) === "") {
            swal({   title: "Missing Information", text: "Please fill in each field before submiting.", type: "error", confirmButtonText: "Back" });
            return false;
        }
       else{
           message = $("#contactform").serializeArray();
           var o = {};
           var submitTime = new Date();
           $.each(message, function() {
                if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                    if (!o[this.name].push) {
                        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                    }
                    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                } else {
                    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                }
            });
           $.ajax({
               url: "http://formspree.io/example@gmail.com", 
               data: {o,submitTime},
               header{

               }
           });
           swal({   title: "Success", text: "Thank you for your enquiry", type:"success", confirmButtonText: "Close" });
           document.getElementById('contactform').reset();
           return false;
       }
   });
```

Comment: Where's the POST request ?

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax request is being posted to formspree.io not S3, so this is a non issue.